# Vue3 add a global plugin after login or after a certain page

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vuejs3, apollo-client, vue-apollo

Libraries:
Vue3 and
Apollo Client v3

Problem:

I am working on a project which has a login page and a protected page. In the current Vue setup, you create Apollo provider and then use `Vue.use(apolloProvider)` which initializes the client.

What I want to achieve, initialize Apollo provider only after the user has logged in as the Authorization header is required to be passed to graphql endpoints. Based on documentation it doesn't seem like there is an option to do so. The reason to do so is, authentication is a separate service at the moment.

Comment: This is XY problem. A user could be logged out eventually, and what then? It should be possible to postpone plugin initialization or change its config later. If it's not documented, this may require to browse plugin source code.

Comment: What about using a second Vue App instance? Since you can create many of them, you can use one exclusive for the Apollo provider.